Noun phrase vs prepostional phrase
I am wondering if a noun phrase can contain a prepostional phrase?
For example in this compound "the industrail revolution across this country" the whole compound is a noun phrase?
Or just the first part,"the industrial revolution", indicates of that?

Look up noun phrase

OP's query:

I am wondering if a noun phrase can contain a proportional phrase?

Yes, the entire compound  "the industrail revolution across this country" is  a noun phrase.
This structure is called a "noun phrase with a prepositional postmodifier.      .
The prepositional phrase "across this country" provides additional information about the scope or location of the industrial revolution, modifying the noun phrase.

Reference The Britannica Dictionary.
Prepositional phrases modify or describe nouns, pronouns, adjectives, adverbs, and verbs. They say something about the relationship between their object and the word they describe/modify.
.
In the phrase "the girl with the long hair" the prepositional phrase is "with the long hair." It tells us something about "the girl.".
.
In the phrase "the book on the table" the prepositional phrase is "on the table." It tells us the location of  "the book.".
Prepositional Phrases

